# Leather lacing at home

Tags: leather

I recently bought tandy lace maker tool for making leather laces. I use good right amount of thickness of leather to make the lace and still the backside of the lace gets fuzzy with grains coming out. This makes the final lacing that i do on leather not professional. How do companies make that even glossy looking leather lace both on the front and back?

Comment: Do you have an image of what you'd like the finished item to look like?

Comment: What kind of leather are you using? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

Your question indictes that you want to make laces that will be viewed from both sides and so need them to both be smooth. The normal [leather making process](https://www.spinneybeck.com/index.php?/about-how-leather-is-made) produces [two types of leather](https://www.leather-dictionary.com/index.php/Split_leather) both of which can be further processed to be smooth on both sides .. you choose based on your need for quality .. I would recommend you go for Grain leather than has been ironed to smooth the inside surface.